# T-SQL query to join tables and combine rows into comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables as follows:

*Users*

```
| Name   | TagsId |  
+--------+--------+  
| Bob    |  3     |  
| Jim    |  2     |  
| Bob    |  2     |   
| Frank  |  3     |  
| Jim    |  1     |
```

*Tags*

```
| Name    | Id  |
+---------+-----+
| web     |  1  |
| desktop |  2  |
| phone   |  3  |
```

My desired result is as follows:

```
| Name  | TagList        |
+-------+----------------+
| Bob   | desktop, phone |
| Jim   | desktop, web   |
| Frank | phone          |
```

I am able to accomplish this in SQL Server 2017 using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    u.name, STRING_AGG (t.name, ', ') as taglist 
FROM 
    users AS u       
LEFT JOIN 
    Tags AS t ON u.TagsId = t.Id 
GROUP BY 
    u.name;
```

But unfortunately my data is in a SQL Server 2016 server so cannot use the `STRING_AGG` function.

How can I accomplish this without `STRING_AGG`?

Comment: I think this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @sean-lange but I cannot create temporary tables in the database as I do not have access. Any other thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Use a table variable then, DECLARE @table Table ( column INT )

Comment: I am guessing you didn't read, or at least understand, the solution found there. There is no need for a temp table. I don't see a single temp table anywhere in the question or any answers for the one I marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @SeanLange, Yeah, I miss interpreted the table that was being created for the example as a necessary step where it is only needed to generate the data for the query. My bad. That said, that example only uses a single table but I think I can adapt it.